# Get response from Flask-RESTPlus in csv

Tags: python, csv, flask-restplus

I have created and REST API using Flask-RESTPlus. I am getting response in json and its fine. Now I have a new requirement to specify **Response content type** as csv or json.

I checked API doc there is nothing mentioned !!

Is it possible to get reponse in csv using Flask-RESTPlus ??

Comment: Can you provide a sample code of what you are doing and how you tried to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get output in csv . It took some time though

`@api.representation('text/csv')
def data_csv(data, code, headers):
    '''Get result in csv '''
    resp = make_response(convert_data(data), code)
    resp.headers.extend(headers)
    return resp`